# How can i show guilds number on status?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

im using discord.py and i wanted to showed the number of servers that my bot currently on
it worked but its not updating what should i fix?

I'm writing on Python (in learning) and i've seen this code from the internet

here's my code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  activity = discord.Game(name=f"k.cmd for help! | {len(bot.guilds)} Guilds", type=3)
  await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)
  print(f"logged in as {bot.user}")
```

Comment: Hi, have you reran your bot? also is this code raising any errors?

Comment: its updated when i restart my bot but i wanted to make it always updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a `while True:` loop like shown in RiveN's answer, that will update the bot's status basically every second which will end up in it getting ratelimited and very laggy.

Use `discord.ext.tasks`:

```py
from discord.ext import tasks #at the start of your code

@tasks.loop(minutes = 1)
async def change_status():
    activity = discord.Game(name=f"k.cmd for help! | {len(bot.guilds)} Guilds", type=3)
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=activity)

@change_status.before_loop
async def before_changing_status():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()

change_status.start()
bot.run(your_token_here)
```

This will update your bot's status every minute, and it will not become laggy while doing so.

Comment: its gave me 'igoring exception in on_ready traceback'

edit: i get it bc my code that i forgot to delete sry.